# how to set content edit access and No module setting access in dotnetnuke 7.4

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7, dotnetnuke-settings

I'm new in dotnetnuke and i have a slider module that has two part,first for it's content control panel which must be editable by site admins and second is the module setting panel itself that must be editable only for host or administrator users,i wonder how can i grant this sort of permission for different users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do this using the ModuleActions call on your VIEW control

```
public ModuleActionCollection ModuleActions
        {
            get
            {
                var actions = new ModuleActionCollection
                    {
                        {
                            GetNextActionID(), Localization.GetString("EditModule", LocalResourceFile), "", "", "",
                            EditUrl(), false, SecurityAccessLevel.Edit, true, false
                        }
                    };
                return actions;
            }
        }
```

The SecurityAccessLevel.Edit there, you have

View, Edit, Admin, Host, ViewPermissions available as options.

Sounds like you want to use the EDIT and HOST options for what you are describing.

Comment: thank you chris,but where can i found the SecurityAccessLevel.Edit?

Comment: This would be in your ModuleActions on the View Control of your module, that implements IActionable

Comment: thank you chris,It's my pleasure to get answer of my question from your side. can you please get me some glance link in dnn module development tutorial in c#?